# Error cargar datos mat-select-list "values.forEach is not a function at MatSelectionList.push"

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

hola tengo un error al intentar cargar datos a un mat-select-list multiple los que tienen el checkbox, de angular material, tengo un servicio rest que me carga un combo con el mat-select-list y funciona para insertar informacion, pero el problema es cuando quiero ver el detalle de esa operacion o editarlo ya que necesito cargar los que ya se seleccionaron previamente, el servicio rest que consumo del detalle no tiene la misma estructura con el que muestro el combo del mat-select-list, solo tiene un campo que es el de codigo y lo regresa como un string de la asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se supone que cada valor de esos es el identificador de los item del arreglo del combo, entonces lo que necesito es que esos al cargar me aparescan seleccionados.

```
documents: new FormControl(codigo)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el codigo de mi html es el siguiente:

```
 <mat-list-item>
                <mat-selection-list formControlName="documents" disabled multiple>
                  <mat-list-option   checkboxPosition="before" *ngFor="let document of setDocuments"
                                   [value]="document.codigoValor">
                    {{document.descripcion}}
                  </mat-list-option>
                </mat-selection-list>
              </mat-list-item>
```

Comment: La pregunta esta un poco confusa. ¿El problema es que las opciones no aparecen seleccionadas? o ¿`documents: new FormControl` no se llena con los objetos que fueron seleccionados?

Comment: el problema es que las opciones no aparecen seleccionadas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La razón por lo que las opciones no aparecen seleccionadas es porque no le estas pasando la propiedad `selected` en `mat-list-option`, acabo de responder la misma pregunta hecha acá [mat-selection-list Seleccionar valor por default Angular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/368957/mat-selection-list-seleccionar-valor-por-default-angular/370343#370343)

Puedes encontrar un ejemplo en este [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/es-stackoverflow-368957)

Debes de asegurarte es pasarle una condicion a la propiedad `selected` para que marque como seleccionada

Comment: mi objeto del servicio no tiene esa propiedad seleccionado, yo creo esa variable en el html [selected]=selectList  y en mi ts el selectList:boolean , pero en ese ejemplo al tratar de asignarle la respuesta a mi selectList, me da  error, en ese ejemplo lo hacen en el contructor yo lo hago en un metodo dentro de la clase del componente

Comment: despues de probar de distintas formas tu solucion funciono para mi!tuve que asignarle el seleccionado como opcional asignar la respuesta del servicio a esa interfaz trabajo bien muchas gracias!

Comment: Que bueno leer que te funcionó!