# mat-selection-list Seleccionar valor por default Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Tengo una tabla de roles de usuario, donde dependiendo del rol que tengan pueden entrar a ciertas "ventanas", para visualizar las ventanas a las que tienen acceso puse las ventanas en un `mat-selection-list` con esta estructura:

```
<mat-selection-list [formControl]="modulos">
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let mod of ventanas" disabled>
    {{mod.Nombre}}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

Los datos de "ventanas" los traigo desde la base de datos, traen Id y nombre. Quiero que aparezcan seleccionadas por default las ventanas a las que cada rol tiene acceso. Para esto ya tengo un `array` que dependiendo el id de cada rol me trae los id de cada ventana a las que tiene acceso. El array es algo así:

```
ListMod=[1,2,3,8,11]; //para el rol con id 1
ListMod=[2,4,5]; //para el rol con id 2
//etc..etc..
```

Intenté con esto:

```
modulos = new FormControl();
anotherlist:[]

mandarData(){
  for(let i of this.ListMod){
    this.anotherlist = this.ListMod
  }
  this.modulos.setValue(this.anotherlist);
}
```

Pero no me funcionó. ¿Hay alguna otra manera de hacerlo o estoy haciendo algo mal?

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos problemas:

1. No le estas asignado el atributo `[selected]` al componente `mat-list-option`

```
<mat-list-option *ngFor="let mod of ventanas" disabled [selected]="mod.seleccionado">
```

2. Al resultado de las ventanas proveniente de la base de datos, se le debe de agregar un estado a cada objeto para determinar si esta seleccionado o no.

Por ejemplo:

```
  this.ventanas = result.map((item) => ({
    ...item,
    seleccionado: this.listMod.some((el) => 
      el === item.id
    )
   }));
```

`result` es el resultado de la solicitud a la base de datos, se itera para agregar la propiedad seleccionado, `this.listMod.some` se encarga de buscar el `id` y verificar si existe en `listMod`, si existe en se le asignar `true`, sino `false`

Cree un ejemplo funcional [acá](https://stackblitz.com/edit/es-stackoverflow-368957)